# Windows Task Manager Crashes Every Time It's Opened. Solutions?

Tags: windows-7, windows

I got the following report:

```
Problem signature:
Problem Event Name: APPCRASH  
Application Name: taskmgr.exe  
Application Version: 6.1.7600.16385  
Application Timestamp: 4a5bc3ee  
Fault Module Name: hostv32.dll  
Fault Module Version: 0.0.0.0  
Fault Module Timestamp: 4c5c027d  
Exception Code: c0000005  
Exception Offset: 0000000000068b73  
OS Version: 6.1.7600.2.0.0.256.48  
Locale ID: 1033  
Additional Information 1: bf4f  
Additional Information 2: bf4f79e8ecbde38b818b2c0e2771a379  
Additional Information 3: d246  
Additional Information 4: d2464c78aa97e6b203cd0fca121f9a58  

Read our privacy statement online:  
http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=104288&clcid=0x0409  

If the online privacy statement is not available, please read our 
privacy statement offline: 
C:\Windows\system32\en-US\erofflps.txt
```

Whenever I open the task manager, within one or two seconds it says that it has stopped working, and giving the above report.

Anyone have solutions?

Answer (score 2):

It sounds to me like you have a virus, which has injected a DLL into all processes, including Task Manager. Often when viruses do this incorrectly, it causes processes to crash. The virus might also be doing something even more devious.

Assuming that the problem doesn't resolve itself after a reboot, you should definitely run a scan with a realiable anti-virus product.

Answer (score 1):

hostv32.dll (the module containing the crashing address) is not a MS provided binary, and should not be loaded in TaskMgr.  I can't find any reference to this module on the web.  Find out where that module came from and you should have your answer.